# Set active control point in script

Tags: python, modifiers, bezier-curves

How do set the control point of a bezier curve to "active" in script in 2.8? Like so:
[image]

I want to hook it to a new object like so:

```
bpy.data.objects['Bezier'].data.splines[0].bezier_points[i].select_control_point = True 
bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
```

but the first line doesn't make it active, and I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Requires selected vertices or active vertex group
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be in edit mode for this to work.

```
import bpy

i = 0  # this is the index of the bezier point you want

points = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']data.splines[0].bezier_points

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

points[i].select_control_point = True

bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

After setting the value, you may need to call:

```
points.update()
```

I can't find any docs on this, but others have had similar issues with this on mesh vertices and calling an update seems to re-synch blender.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format instead

```
curve.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].select_control_point = True
```

Just make sure you select the right point.